# mongoose $text search for specific keys

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a `User` Schema and I set some indexes like this:

```
UserSchema.index({firstName: 'text', lastName: 'text', city: 'text', area: 'text'});
```

I want to use the `$search` operator and find data based on some specific keys, for example, I want to find the users based on a given city or area. Is it possible?

For example, the next query I want only to search in `city` and `area`:

```
User.find({ $text: { $search: 'London' } }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(doc);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB you can have at most one text index .

From official mongodb docs :

> **IMPORTANT**
>
> A collection can have at most one text index.

From the index that you have created in your schema, your query will look for 'London' in `firstName` , `lastName`, `city` and `area`, and it will all such docs where it can find `London` in any of those fields.

If you want to search for a specific word, only in one field(lets say `city`),  you can use `regex` matching, and you can use case-insenstive match to ignore case.

Try this:

```
User.find({city : {$regex : ".*London.*" ,$options:"i"}},function(err,docs){
    ...
})
```

Here `$options : "i"` is for case insensitivity.
It will return all the docs with 'london' anywhere in the `city` field.

You can read more about MongoDB $regex operator in [official mongodb $regex docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

**Note**:
You cannot use `text-searching` and `regex matching` both in a single query, you will have to choose one over another, whatever fits your scenario

Comment: I know about regex, but I don't want to use it because I'm concerned about the speed. Anyway, I will accept your answer, since there is no other way to do it

Comment: there is a small problem in this because it will return data with lo also